# Draw square with OpenLayers 3

Tags: polygon, openlayers, openlayers-2

I am starting to convert old code of OpenLayers 2 to OpenLayers 3. In the old version you could make polygon shape based of the amount of sides like in the example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/r9g1odce/4/

I was looking for the same functionality in OpenLayers 3 but couldn't find any... is there something I am missing?

The best example I found for drawing and modifying features is here
but there is no square shape:

http://acanimal.github.io/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter07_07_editing_features.html

The code I am using for polygon drawing is:

```
drawInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: featureOverlay.getFeatures(),
    type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ('Polygon') 
  });

map.addInteraction(drawInteraction);
```

The types can be found here:
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/apidoc/ol.geom.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily recreate the functionality with `ol.interaction.DragBox`. The interaction has a `boxend` event, which propagates an object with a `getGeometry()` function.

The geometry can be added to a new feature, which can be added to the vector source. The geometry can be logged directly from the `boxend` event handler, but the source object also has an `addfeature` event.

To create a dragbox interaction, you have to define the condition on which the interaction activates (I think it is shiftKey by default), and the style of the box.

```
var interaction = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
    condition: ol.events.condition.noModifierKeys,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: [0, 0, 255, 1]
        })
    })
});
```

The geometry of the last dragged box then gets extracted by the event handler, and added to the vector source.

```
interaction.on('boxend', function(evt){
    var geom = evt.target.getGeometry();
    console.log(geom);
    var feat = new ol.Feature({geometry: geom});
    source.addFeature(feat);
});
```

See how it works in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/fd7tzyjg/).

Comment: I asked this question also in stackoverflow wasn't sure were to put this question so decided both, It will be great if you answer it there as well:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744743/draw-square-openlayers-3/29745360#29745360